# Wrong ic_launcher icon in my app

Tags: android

I'm developing an app for `Honeycomb` and got this really quirky problem.

I've changed app icon (`ic_launcher`) in every `drawable` folder and make sure it is right in the manifest, but instead Ive got an standard "`settings`" icon in launcher (in app itself it's right).

I've cleaned the project, searched for every single wrong line, no results.

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Show us the screenshot of your both drawable folders and your `manifest.xml` file. And, try to uninstall the app and run again.

Comment: Try clearing the cache before uninstalling the app from your device.

Comment: It happened also to me on Galaxy tab 2 (10.1). Fixed like Avin suggested.

Comment: I've solved using "Project -> Clean..." on Eclipse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weird problem

Just change `@drawable/appicon` with your icon in your `Manifest.xml` like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.droid.MyApplication">
...
</application>
```

Comment: It seems eclipse was not updating the /bin/res/crunch/drawable-{?}dpi folders, but after manually changing it in the Manifest.xml and renaming the resources under /res/drawables-{?}dpi the icon was refreshed on the next compilation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the icon appeared correctly after I rebooted the device. I had followed the above suggestions, though.

Answer (score 1):

Go to AndroidManifest and edit :

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_custom_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_custom_launcher">
    /* ....  */
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe happened,  because of didn't uninstall the old app with old launcher icon. So, just try to uninstall your application. And, place the differnet size of icons in both `drawable` folders.

Give the icon name into your `AndroidManifest.xml` file `<application>` tag.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And, run your application.

Comment: It was uninstalled, on different device problem exists too. Everything you said I've done numerous times. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @mglisty Actually, what is your icon name? Did you check whether both drawable has the icon. And, you'd given the same name in your manifest file?

Comment: Yeah, it's icon_launcher in drawable an the same in manifest. Also, the icon is good in top bar.